# Limit of a real function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Evaluating

```
Limit[2^x Log[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1]
```

(right limit) gives correctly the answer

> ```
> -∞
> ```

but the command

```
Limit[2^x Log[x], x -> 0, Direction -> 1]
```

(left limit) gives again

> ```
> -∞
> ```

The same in *WolframAlpha*. What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct in that the limit of the complex logarithm on the standard branch, as $x\to 0$ from below, should better be written as $-\infty + i \pi$.

The reason why *Mathematica* doesn't give this result is that it uses a *polar representation* for infinity in the complex plane. You can see this by doing

```
FullForm[Limit[2^x Log[x], x -> 0, Direction -> 1]]
```

> `DirectedInfinity[-1]`

This [`DirectedInfinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedInfinity.html) expresses the fact that the imaginary part goes to a constant whereas the real part diverges.

However, in complex analysis it is often necessary to retain constants such as the one in $-\infty + i \pi$, e.g., to choose integration paths correctly. If you want to get that constant from a `Limit`, I think the easiest way to do it is to forcibly do the limits of the real and imaginary parts separately:

```
Table[
 Limit[h[2^x Log[x]], x -> 0, Direction -> 1], {h, {Re, Im}}]

(* ==> {-Infinity, Pi} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a correct result.It is best to illustrate on the plot.

[image]

```
f[x_] := 2^x*Log[x];
{Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> 1], 
Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1]}
```

> $\{-\infty ,-\infty \}$

```
Plot[{Re@f[x], f[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> Bottom, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-10, 3}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a correct result. The computation below may help to see this.

```
Table[2^x Log[x], {x, -(10.^Range[-1, -10, -1])}]
```

> ```
> (* Out[48]= {-2.14838785758 + 2.93120959177 I, -4.57335995192 + 
>   3.119892088 I, -6.90296884693 + 3.13941582202 I, -9.20970198196 + 
>   3.14137490253 I, -11.5128456637 + 3.1415708778 I, -13.8155009818 + 
>   3.141590476 I, -16.1180945337 + 3.14159243583 I, -18.4206806163 + 
>   3.14159263181 I, -20.7232658226 + 3.14159265141 I, -23.0258509283 + 
>   3.14159265337 I} *)
> ```

The values are heading to negative infinity, on a path near Pi units north of the negative axis. Remark: for better or worse, Mathematica does not have a notion of "infinite real part plus finite imaginary part", so `-Infinity+I*Pi` just becomes `-Infinity`.